# C++ Unintialized struct member - field does not exist

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have the below structures in my C++ code.

```
struct XYZ {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

struct Data {
  XYZ xyz_point;
  double item_1;
  double item_2;
  double item_3;
};
```

In my code I create a vector of structure `Data`.

```
std::vector<Data> data_vector;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   Data data_point_1;
   data_point_1.xyz_point.x = 10.0;
   data_point_1.xyz_point.y = 11.0;
   data_point_1.xyz_point.z = 12.0;
   data_point_1.item_1 = 13.0;
   data_point_1.item_2 = 14.0;
   data_point_1.item_3 = 15.0;
   data_vector.push_back(data_point_1);
}
```

Code build successful without any errors, however during the CPP_Check I get the below warnings/error. `data_point_1` does not have the field `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
[test.cc:122]: (error: uninitStructMember) Uninitialized struct member: data_point_1.x
[test.cc:122]: (error: uninitStructMember) Uninitialized struct member: data_point_1.y
[test.cc:122]: (error: uninitStructMember) Uninitialized struct member: data_point_1.z
```

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`push_back` requires a default constructor. The compiler is able to supply that, but it doesn't initialise the `double`s.

CPP_Check is spotting that.

One fix is to use `emplace_back` instead with the *initialiser-list* syntax. That doesn't require a default constructor. Another option is to supply a default constructor that initialises the members.